# Altering a matrix parameter within a method changes the original matrix

Tags: c#, matrix

when I call method called Vyměň (it has matrix "matice" as a formal parameter), but when the method ends, real matrix "a" (which shloud not be changed) a is overwritten. Why?

```
static int[,] Vyměň(int sloupec, int[,] matice, int [] vektor)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matice.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            matice[i, sloupec] = vektor[i];
        }
        return matice;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] a = new int[3,4];
        int[] b = new int[3];

        a = Čti(); //Method Čti works fine
        for( int i = 0; i <3; i++)
        {
            b[i] = a[i, 3];
        }

        int detA = determinanty.det3(a);
        Vypis(a);
        int detX = determinanty.det3(Vyměň(0, a, b));
        Vypis(a);
        int detY = determinanty.det3(Vyměň(1, a,b));
        Vypis(a);
        int detZ = determinanty.det3(Vyměň(2, a,b));
        Vypis(a);

        double x = detX / detA;
        double y = detY / detA;
        double z = detZ / detA;
        Console.WriteLine("kořen x = {0}", x);
        Console.WriteLine("kořen y = {0}", y);
        Console.WriteLine("kořen z = {0}", z);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are passed by reference in C#, You are changing the value of the matrix inside the method.

If you dont want to do so, use Clone of the array to pass in the method.

Comment: Arrays are not passed by reference... in fact, _nothing_ is passed by reference by default. You're passing a reference to an array _by value_. There is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I guess by formal parameter you mean value type..
but since you are using arrays(reference type) they are passed as reference types.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are reference type - so variable of such type into a method does not create copy of the values, but rater let method to modify that value.

If you need real "value" semantic for array/matrix type you need to create your own type that forces you to create copy to modify values (similar to `string`).